To check if a given relation on a set is poset.
Given a relation $R$ on sets defined by
$R=\{(A,B):A∩B=B\}$. I have to check whether it is poset or not?
My attempt:
I assumed that $A∩B=B$ gives the set which is on the RHS of intersection.
So, reflexive property is satisfied as $A∩A=A$.
Anti-Symmetry: $A∩B=B$ and $B∩A=A$ will be satisfied only if $A=B$. So, it is anti-asymmetric.
Transitive: $A∩B=B$ ______ (1)
and $B∩C=C$ ___________ (2)
We have to check for $A∩C=C$.
$A∩C=A∩(B∩C)$ _______ from (2)
= $(A∩B)∩C$
= $B∩C$
= $C$.
so, $R$ is a poset. Did I prove it correctly?
If not kindly rectify me. Thanks for the help.

Yes, it seems correct.

I would say that your proof of antisymmetry could be more straightforward, if you already proved (or can prove) that $A\cap B=B\cap A$ for any sets $A$ and $B,$ for then $$B=A\cap B=B\cap A=A,$$ so that $B=A$ by the transitive property of equality.

Yes, it is correct, and an alternate way to do that is as follows:
$$A\cap B=B\iff B\subseteq A$$
and so $(A,B)\subseteq R$ iff $B\subseteq A$. Then, the three properties follow more trivially.

Oh my God. That is wonderful. Nice approach. Thanks a lot.
